# PHP parsing error

Tags: php, parsing

I have a string like this:

```
{\"lat\":37.790388261934424,\"lng\":-122.46047996826172},{\"lat\":37.789608231530124,\"lng\":-122.46344112701416}
```

And when I tried to get rid of the double quotes with something like this:

```
$data = str_replace('\"','"',$date);
```

I got this error:

```
Unexpected character in input:  '\\' (ASCII=92) state=1
```

I also got that error running the following without the previous line:

```
$data = json_decode($data);
```

Any ideas why this is happening?  Is this a sign that I am escaping twice somewhere?  Or is the issue something else?

Comment: Did you try `stripslashes` yet? Nest it twice, if need be.

Comment: can you please show us the full code of assigning the variable up to the json_decode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `str_replace()` to strip off slashes. Use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

Something like this:

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($data));
```